# not able to deploy ear into jboss 6 which is working in jboss4

Tags: jboss

When we deploy ear in jboss 4 it is working ,But when we try to deploy same ear in jboss 6 facing issue like below

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:89) [:2.5.6.SEC01]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70) [:2.5.6.SEC01]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) [:2.5.6.SEC01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove xml-apis and xercesImp dependencies. These dependencies are provided by JBoss. If it doesn't help, could you post some other informations? pom.xml or a dependency tree. Here is a link for the supported componets by JBoss EAP 6: https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6